# Select multiple columns from the same table without tables union

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to create a query to select several columns from a table, and show the results as a single column. I know I can do this with this query:

```
select a from Z
union
select b from Z
union 
select c from Z
union 
select d from Z
....
```

But in my case, table Z is a sub-query of about 50 lines, that I would not want to copy and paste. So I would like to have this in a query where Z appears only once. I don't know if this is possible.

Do you know a way to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Depending on your version of Oracle, you could look at the UNPIVOT function or if you don't want to repeat the `Z` query look at a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a [*WITH clause*](http://psoug.org/reference/with.html):

```
with Z as (
    select ... from ... -- <<== Put your big query here
)
select a from Z
union
select b from Z
union 
select c from Z
union 
select d from Z
```

The `with` clause at the top makes `Z` available to the remaining parts of your query without having to repeat yourself.

Here is a [demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f7a0c/4).

Answer (score 3):

From Oracle 11gR1 and up, you could use `unpivot` operator, ensure, of course that all columns are of the same datatype:

```
SQL> select val
  2    from (select 1 col1
  3               , 2 col2   
  4               , 3 col3
  5            from dual)
  6  unpivot(
  7    val for col in (col1, col2, col3)
  8  )
  9  ;

       VAL
----------
         1
         2
         3
```